Thin biconvex converging lens problem
I have been stuck with this problem for around some time (not that much). Suppose you have a converging lens; biconvex and its thin.
You have these standard rules of ray tracing, which I will summarize here:

A ray entering a converging lens parallel to its axis passes through the focal point F of the lens on the other side.
A ray passing through the center of either a converging or a diverging lens does not change direction.
A ray entering a converging lens through its focal point exits parallel to its axis.

The other rules don't hold for a converging lens. Here is my question, suppose, a ray crosses 2F (a point twice the focal distance away from the optical center). What will happen to that ray on the other side of the lens? 
This random question struck my mind quite randomly, and I couldn't figure an exact answer to it. First, my brain thought that since this is a converging lens, the ray definitely has to bend towards the principal axis. But where exactly I don't know. 
I don't even know whether this question is legitimate or can such a scenario even exist?
My physics education only lasts till high school. 
EDIT:
I came across this interesting simulation.

Sorry for the bad handwriting, but after tweaking the position of the object, such that one of the rays goes through twice the focal distance(from the optical center) [measured through a ruler they provided in the site itself], I found that the ray returned at twice the focal distance from the other focus (on the other side). 
I am not sure how accurate is this simulation? Are there evidences for such a claim?

This LibreTexts chapter on Lenses might help.

I had a brief look on the article. The rules of ray tracing is similar to what I have outlined. In fact, I had already cross-referenced ray tracing rules from this site only.
It didn't help me very much, except clarifying my understanding of ray tracing further.
Another interesting sub-question to answer is how can we express such a system quantitatively? + I don't know whether such a situation is legitimate or possible.

I think a better rule for a convex lens is - "All parallel rays through a lens meet in one point of the focal plane" - this point is (obviously) the point where the ray through the center of the lens meets the focal plane. (All your three rules follow this this more intuitive one.)

Construction rule:

Draw arbitrary incoming ray

Draw parallel ray through center of lens

find intersection in center ray with (image-side) focal plane

connect you incoming ray with this intersecting point



Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Seeing your solution:
Its the defining characteristic of a converging lens. All ray tracing rules follow from this. But I don't see an immediate continuation into the solution of my problem!

If you agree on the rule then your outgoing ray is defined by 2 points (point 1: where the incoming ray meets the lens, point 2: the intersection point in the focal plane). Connecting the two points and extending to infinity (to the right) is the path of the outgoing ray.

Thank you, I will try it out, and let you know!

Yep, found the solution. You were incredibly helpful. Thank you!

If you want to locate an image formed by a lens by means of ray tracing, you need to consider an extended object, traditionally an arrow perpendicular to the axis, with its tail on the axis. Then apply your ray tracing rules to rays that originate from the arrowhead, that is from an off-axis point. You'll need just two of the three rays specified, but the third will serve as a check. Works like magic, in your case to locate the (real) image at 2 from the optical centre of the lens and on the other side of the lens.

Summary (incoming ray defined by angle $\alpha$ and intersection with optical axis $x$, outgoing ray intersects with optical axis at $l$):
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{y}&=\frac{z}{f},\qquad\frac{y}{l}=\frac{z}{l-f}\\
\rightarrow l&=\frac{f\tan^2\alpha}{\tan^2\alpha-f/x}
\end{align}
($z$ distance of intersection in focal plane from optical axis)

